# VBA - Change cell value when clicked from/to yes/no for merged cells

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a form that will give the user the choice to pick from 7 different options whcih will all be default blank. When they click the cell next to the option it will change from blank to "yes" and when clicked again it will remove the text and so on. The issue I have its the cell that is clickable from blank to "yes" is merged between R33 and S33. The code works on the cell R33 alone but not when I merge them. Can you help me out with this please?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  If Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("R33")) Is Nothing Then
      Select Case Target.Value
      Case ""
        Target.Value = "yes"
      Case "yes"
        Target.Value = ""
      End Select
      Range("A1").Select
    End If
  End If
  Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)

    On Error GoTo Worksheet_SelectionChange_Error

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Debug.Print Target.Cells.Count  'just FYI, remove it later

    If Not Intersect(Target.Cells(1), Range("R33").MergeArea) Is Nothing Then

        Select Case Target.Cells(1)
        Case "yes"
            Target.Cells(1) = vbNullString
        Case vbNullString
            Target.Cells(1) = "yes"
        End Select

    End If

    Range("A1").Select
    Application.EnableEvents = True

   On Error GoTo 0
   Exit Sub

Worksheet_SelectionChange_Error:

    MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & " (" & Err.Description & ")
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

The merged cells are a bit evil in Excel, but if you play around a bit you can achieve what you need:

- `Target.Cells.Count` is equal to the number of merged cells, thus it is never `1`. I have deleted it;
- `Target.Cells(1)` is the way to refer the first cell of the `MergedArea`;
- `Range("R33").MergeArea` is a good way to check the intersect;
- As sometimes while executing `_SelectionChange` event, you may get an error and then leave the `Application.EnableEvents = False`, it is a good practice to use an Error Catcher, which sets it back to `True`;

Comment: great stuff bud! can i ask another favour... im looking to add this to multiple cells R35, R37, R39 and R41. can this be added in into line 3 or will i have to create this whole code for each cell?

Comment: @SuperDood - it is doable, I guess. But is probably a good idea to ask it  as a separate question.

Comment: Good addition of the Error Catcher, and well explained.

Comment: @Vityata thanks mate. im trying to avoid using the same code for each line so youve given me what i need.